# Qt creator - how can I enable snaplines?

Tags: c#, qt, qt-creator

when I developed apps in C#, in visual studio designer there are lines which help with positioning form elements, e.g. it helps me, when I want to place one button right under another, on same X pos, when they have same X or Y snapline appear. can I enable this or similar feature in QtCreator? It's hard to make nice gui without it.

here is picture of snaplines in visual studio C# designer:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzglj.png]

Comment: There are no snaplines, there are layouts.

Answer (score 3):

To make nice GUI in Qt Creator you need to read about layouts:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html

There are examples of basic layouts in documentations:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html

What you show on your image, it is called Vertical Layout. Layouts can be within each other and you can create very complex interface through them. It will be resized correctly together with window.